# Asp.Net Core 2.0 with VSO CI - tsc 2.6.2 error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-pipelines

I have Asp.Net Core 2.0 with React solution and using VSTS CI build. During the build phase, I am getting an error -

```
node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts(109,81): Error TS2344: 
Build:Type 'ChangeTargetHTMLAttributes<T>' does not satisfy the 
constraint 'DOMAttributes<T>'.
```

I am using React 15.0 and my `tsconfig.json` content is -

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["webpack-env"],
    "noImplicitThis": false
  },
  "exclude": ["bin", "node_modules"]
}
```

My CI pipeline is:

1. Use NuGet 4.4.1
2. NuGet restore
3. dotnet restore
4. *Build Web project* (I am getting error at this point)
5. Deploy

Comment: The React type file (`node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts`) should have a big comment at the top specifying the version of React it is for and the version of TypeScript that React uses for that version. What version are those? I'm wondering if the type definitions are compatible with an older version of TypeScript

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: What's the task of Build Web project and how do you configure this task?

Comment: At first I was choosing "Azure Web App" template and I was getting the above error. Now I chose "ASP.NET Core" template for build phase and created a separate release. Choosing "ASP.NET Core" did not give me the above error.

Comment: Do you mean the issue has been solved with ASP.NET Core template?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting above error when I used "Azure Web App" template. When I used "ASP.NET Core" template for CI build phase and created a separate release for CD, I did not get above error.

So basically using "ASP.NET Core" template was the right thing as I was building an ASP.NET Core solution.